# Countif loop on external excel sheets

Tags: vba, excel

Currently i'm trying to consolidate the information from 3000 different xls sheets into one file.

The master file looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/258j1.png

All the other excels are contained in 1 folder like this. They are only 1 sheet each.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBb8R.png

and lastly would be that the information inside the files are like this

http:// i.imgur.com/w3erGgN.png

I'm trying to count the number of "pos", "neg" and "neu" inside the files and consolidate on the master sheet and the current way i'm doing is to manually input countif codes while leaving the document open. Is there any other way to make it faster? I've tried sumproduct but it never works. it only returns 0 as i think it might be the wildcard problem.

I think the following code could be of use to me but I'm not sure how to code it such that it works accordingly.

```
Sub RunCodeOnAllXLSFiles()
Dim lCount As Long
Dim wbResults As Workbook
Dim wbCodeBook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

On Error Resume Next
    Set wbCodeBook = ThisWorkbook
        With Application.FileSearch
            .NewSearch
            'Change path to suit
            .LookIn = "C:\MyDocuments\TestResults"
            .FileType = msoFileTypeExcelWorkbooks
            'Optional filter with wildcard
            '.Filename = "Book*.xls"
                If .Execute > 0 Then 'Workbooks in folder
                    For lCount = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count 'Loop through all
                        'Open Workbook x and Set a Workbook variable to it
                        Set wbResults = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=.FoundFiles(lCount), UpdateLinks:=0)

                    'DO YOUR CODE HERE

                    wbResults.Close SaveChanges:=False
                Next lCount
            End If
    End With
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Please help.

Comment: "I think the following code could be of use to me but I'm not sure how to code it such that it works accordingly." This is not helpful - it sounds like you haven't even attempted to run the code above, and that you pulled it from somewhere online. If you can't read the code, don't run it. You run the risk of getting in over your head, and being able to fix problems your code may cause, especially if your exact requirements change. What a shock it would be to your employer, if you were unable to explain why your own file works (or, especially, doesn't)!

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Why not VTC then?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to receive the most effective help here. Specifically, tell us what in your code is not working the way you desire and what errors you get, etc., etc.

Comment: `FileSearch` is no longer part of Excel VBA (since XL2007?) - you should use `Dir()` to loop over your files. Plenty of examples here on SO which cover that.

Comment: Check out http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Loop%20Through%20Folder and  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XsvI9i2z7s

Answer (score 0):

```
            Sub Merge()
            Path = "C:\path to the folder\"
            Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
              Do While Filename <> ""
              Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
                 For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
                 Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
              Next Sheet
                 Workbooks(Filename).Close
                 Filename = Dir()
              Loop
            End Sub
```

Found here: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/456-combine-multiple-workbooks.html